# Are lamed and nun interchangeable letters?

Tags: aleph-bet-letters

Shulamite and Shunamite seem to be used interchangeably in Tanach when describing certain Na'arah women.
For example, in the story of Elisha, David in his old age( with Abishag) and in the Song of Songs.   Are the "lamed" and the "nun" telling us something I need to understand?

Comment: Not everyone agrees that שולמית in Shir Hashirim is identical with שונמית of the other two stories; various commentaries on that verse connect it rather with שלם, "complete" or a poetic name for Jerusalem, for example. It is certainly true that lamed and nun do interchange in other contexts, for example נשכה in Nehemiah 13:7 in place of לשכה in the verses surrounding that.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/80213/interchangeable-usage-of-hebrew-letters-such-as-beis-and-vav-etc

Comment: Your question asks whether the the letters are telling us something. What do you mean by that? That's a very unclear question, though maybe the problem is on this reader's end. And then your title asks something seemingly entirely different: whether the letters are interchangeable.

Answer (score 2):

The letters ד ת ט ל נ are all related. They are known to some as "dentals" because these sounds rely on very much on teeth.

See [Ramban Genesis 25,3](https://www.sefaria.org/Ramban_on_Genesis.25.3.1?lang=bi) who states explicitly that lamed and nun are often interchanged.